# Batch file to check IP address, and set location based octet

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've pieced together a batch file based on info I've found here. Oddly, an earlier version appeared to work correctly at home, once I took it to work, it didn't. And all my modifications are failing to fix it. My boss and I are stuck.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:" %%f in (`ipconfig ^| findstr /c:"IPv4 Address"`) do (
    for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=. " %%a in ("%%f") do (
        set octetA=%%a set octetB=%%b set octetC=%%c set octetD=%%d 
        if %octetB% equ 10 goto :setschool
        )
    )

:setschool
if %octetC% geq 0 if %octetC% leq 3 set school=DIC
if %octetC% geq 16 if %octetC% leq 19 set school=AT
if %octetC% geq 48 if %octetC% leq 51 set school=BE
if %octetC% geq 64 if %octetC% leq 67 set school=BH
if %octetC% geq 80 if %octetC% leq 83 set school=CN
if %octetC% geq 112 if %octetC% leq 115 set school=LC
if %octetC% geq 128 if %octetC% leq 131 set school=LX
if %octetC% geq 144 if %octetC% leq 147 set school=RG
if %octetC% geq 160 if %octetC% leq 163 set school=UN
if %octetC% geq 176 if %octetC% leq 179 set school=WA
if %octetC% geq 192 if %octetC% leq 195 set school=WI
if %octetC% geq 208 if %octetC% leq 211 set school=BOE


echo %school%
goto :eof
```

It errors out at the first 'if', because octetB hasn't been set to anything yet. Yet the code just before it should have set it. All of our wired DHCP addresses start with 10.10., which is why it's checking for 10, which should mean it ignores our wireless, auto configed IPs, and virtual nics. If I manually run the lines before the 'if', it produces what I expect, with the  octets being set correctly.

Comment: Adding ampersands may help, `set "octetA=%%a" & set "octetB=%%b" & set "octetC=%%c" & set "octetD=%%d"`. In addition to that, currently when your loop has finished, it will automatically run the `:setschool` labelled section, so I'd recommend that you implement something to prevent that. Otherwise regardless of the value of `%octetB%` that section will still run.

Comment: It could be grabbing another network card (like wireless) and getting wrong information.  Run `ipconfig | findstr /c:"IPv4 Address"` directly from the command line and see what it returns.

Comment: Also, it might be "ip address" instead of "ipv4 address".

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try. I actually just added the :setschool section, and since it's erroring before that, I haven't started fixing that up yet.

Comment: It's ipv4..and as I said, if I run the lines before that 'if', they return correctly.

Comment: Oh duh!!  I missed where your first `if` is.  You need delayed expansion.

Comment: There could be multiple network interfaces that have an IPv4 address active.how are you going to determine the correct one?

Comment: well, these would be workstations that have been newly imaged, and only have 1 nic in them. Even on my workstation, with vmware, and other adapters, the addresses they have don't fall into the 10.10. range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the output of `ipconfig` is different at home and at work. Do you run the same operating systems on them? With the same language setting? Do the ipconfig outputs on both machines contain a `IPv4 Address` line when checked manually?
But I cannot tell anything without knowing the "earlier version that worked" you mentioned.
You can try using a simpler search String that is common on both machines, like `IPv4`. And maybe you want to add the `/I` switch to the `findStr` call to set it to "ignore case".

Try checking for equality with `if "%%b" == "10" goto setschool` (remove the colon, replace %octetB%). I think %octetB% is only available inside the for loop if you work with delayed expansion of variables.

You need to put each `set` command on its own line inside the for loop.

With these changes it works for me at least under Win10.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I find which IP subnet our machines are using:

```
ipconfig^|findstr /i /c:"ip address"^|findstr /c:"10.11.1"&&set loc=AAA&&goto :continue
ipconfig^|findstr /i /c:"ipv4 address"^|findstr /c:"10.11.1"&&set loc=AAA&&goto ipconfig^|findstr /i /c:"ip address"^|findstr /c:"192.168.4."&&set loc=BBB&&goto :continue
:continue
ipconfig^|findstr /i /c:"ipv4 address"^|findstr /c:"192.168.4."&&set loc=BBB&&goto :continue
set loc=unknown
:continue
```

I think "ip address" is from WinXP or Win7.

Answer (score 0):

You need delayed expansion.

**untested**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:" %%f in (`ipconfig ^| findstr /c:"IPv4 Address"`) do (
    for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=. " %%a in ("%%f") do (
        set octetA=%%a & set octetB=%%b & set octetC=%%c & set octetD=%%d 
        if "!octetB!" equ "10" goto :setschool
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `Rem`arked batch file example, showing the fix for your issues, as per my initial comment:

```batch-file
@Echo Off

Rem Undefine any existing octet variables.

For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('Set octet 2^>NUL') Do Set "%%G="

Rem Retrieve the IPv4 string from the IPConfig command.
Rem And set each octet to individual variables.

For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=:" %%G In (
    '"%__AppDir__%ipconfig.exe 2>NUL | %__Appdir__%find.exe "IPv4""'
) Do For /F "Tokens=1-4 Delims=. " %%H In ("%%G"
) Do Set "octet1=%%H" & Set "octet2=%%I" & Set "octet3=%%J" & Set "octet4=%%K"

Rem Check to see if any octet variables are defined, i.e. IPv4 found.
Rem If not print message, wait for response and end the script.

Set octet >NUL 2>&1 || (Echo IPConfig failed to retrieve an IP address.
    Pause & GoTo :EOF)

Rem From here you can make your comparisons:

Rem First ensure that a variable named school is not defined.

Set "school="

Rem Check to see if your second octet was 10.
Rem Then make your comparisons using the value of the third octet.

If %octet2% Equ 10 If Defined octet3 (
    If %octet3% GEq 0   If %octet3% LEq 3   Set "school=DIC"
    If %octet3% GEq 16  If %octet3% LEq 19  Set "school=AT"
    If %octet3% GEq 48  If %octet3% LEq 51  Set "school=BE"
    If %octet3% GEq 64  If %octet3% LEq 67  Set "school=BH"
    If %octet3% GEq 80  If %octet3% LEq 83  Set "school=CN"
    If %octet3% GEq 112 If %octet3% LEq 115 Set "school=LC"
    If %octet3% GEq 128 If %octet3% LEq 131 Set "school=LX"
    If %octet3% GEq 144 If %octet3% LEq 147 Set "school=RG"
    If %octet3% GEq 160 If %octet3% LEq 163 Set "school=UN"
    If %octet3% GEq 176 If %octet3% LEq 179 Set "school=WA"
    If %octet3% GEq 192 If %octet3% LEq 195 Set "school=WI"
    If %octet3% GEq 208 If %octet3% LEq 211 Set "school=BOE")

Rem As your comparisons do not currently cover all possible octet values,
Rem This is a check to see if the school variable was actually defined.
Rem If not print message, otherwise print the content of the school variable.

If Not Defined school (Echo The school variable was not defined.
    Echo Reason: & If %octet2% Neq 10 (Echo The second octet was not 10.
    ) Else If Defined octet3 (Echo The third octet failed the comparisons.
        ) Else Echo Your returned IP address was corrupted.) Else Echo %school%

Rem Wait to ensure that any messages can be read, if not run from cmd.exe.

Pause

Rem End script.

GoTO :EOF
```

The script includes some additions designed to provide reasonable feedback if errors occur.

---

*Feel free to use this un`Rem`arked version for completion or in your production environment*.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('Set octet 2^>NUL')Do Set "%%G="
For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=:" %%G In (
    '"%__AppDir__%ipconfig.exe 2>NUL|%__Appdir__%find.exe "IPv4""'
)Do For /F "Tokens=1-4Delims=. " %%H In ("%%G"
)Do Set "octet1=%%H"&Set "octet2=%%I"&Set "octet3=%%J"&Set "octet4=%%K"
Set octet>NUL 2>&1||(Echo IPConfig failed to retrieve an IP address.
    Pause&GoTo :EOF)
Set "school="
If %octet2% Equ 10 If Defined octet3 (
    If %octet3% GEq 0 If %octet3% LEq 3 Set "school=DIC"
    If %octet3% GEq 16 If %octet3% LEq 19 Set "school=AT"
    If %octet3% GEq 48 If %octet3% LEq 51 Set "school=BE"
    If %octet3% GEq 64 If %octet3% LEq 67 Set "school=BH"
    If %octet3% GEq 80 If %octet3% LEq 83 Set "school=CN"
    If %octet3% GEq 112 If %octet3% LEq 115 Set "school=LC"
    If %octet3% GEq 128 If %octet3% LEq 131 Set "school=LX"
    If %octet3% GEq 144 If %octet3% LEq 147 Set "school=RG"
    If %octet3% GEq 160 If %octet3% LEq 163 Set "school=UN"
    If %octet3% GEq 176 If %octet3% LEq 179 Set "school=WA"
    If %octet3% GEq 192 If %octet3% LEq 195 Set "school=WI"
    If %octet3% GEq 208 If %octet3% LEq 211 Set "school=BOE")
If Not Defined school (Echo The school variable was not defined.
    Echo Reason:&If %octet2% Neq 10 (Echo The second octet was not 10.
    )Else If Defined octet3 (Echo The third octet failed the comparisons.
        )Else Echo Your returned IP address was corrupted.)Else Echo %school%
Pause
GoTO :EOF
```